# How to figure out number of files in specific folder on server?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, count, directory

I have been trying to find a way to get the count of how many files are in a folder called "images", which is in a folder I am already in.

This is the code I have been trying but I have been getting an error message:

Code:

```
count = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images"), 
"(asterisk symbol).(asterisk symbol)").Count()
```

The error message says it can't find the path.

Comment: Apart of your non-existent path problem, you should use `Directory.EnumerateFiles(..).Count()` since it does not need to create an array full of strings just to count them.

Comment: I had tried this but I got the same error. count = Directory.EnumerateFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\images"), "(asterisk).(asterisk)").Count()

Comment: I know, thats why i have posted it as comment. It doesn't solve your main issue.

Comment: Does the AppPool user identity have read permissions on that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging a problem, break the line of code in to smaller pieces to make it earier to see.  I would first print out the value of `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images")`.  Then see if that's a real folder. .

Comment: I used your method and sure enough I was able to figure it out! Thank you for your advice.